# AWS CloudFormer stack creation failed with (Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I was trying to use AWS CloudFormer to create a template for my existing resources, however, the CloudFormer stack creation failed multiple times without an obvious reason. below you can find the full log, I tried to increase the timeout in the options to 100 minute and I got the same results:

```
22:16:49 UTC+0300   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Instance  WebServer   Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration
21:45:58 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  WebServer   Resource creation Initiated
21:45:56 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  WebServer   
21:45:54 UTC+0300   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CFNInstanceProfile  
21:43:54 UTC+0300   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::Policy    CFNRolePolicy   
21:43:54 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Policy    CFNRolePolicy   Resource creation Initiated
21:43:53 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CFNInstanceProfile  Resource creation Initiated
21:43:53 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Policy    CFNRolePolicy   
21:43:52 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CFNInstanceProfile  
21:43:50 UTC+0300   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::Role  CFNRole 
21:43:44 UTC+0300   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebServerSecurityGroup  
21:43:43 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebServerSecurityGroup  Resource creation Initiated
21:43:39 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  CFNRole Resource creation Initiated
21:43:27 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebServerSecurityGroup  
21:43:27 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  CFNRole 
21:43:18 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  AWSCloudFormer  User Initiated
```

Comment: There may be a problem with the AMI that you're using.  Can you create an EC2 instance from it manually?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Parameters, specify a username and password. It is mandatory to create the instance.

Comment: wow good catch. kind of annoying this isn't handled as validation when entering information on that part of the process

Comment: Wow, adding the username & password parameter solved my issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue. What properties for the EC2 Instance would I be passing these user name and password values into? Do you have some form of code example?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation is waiting from a notification from the CloudFormer WebServer instance, specified in the CloudFormer template using a [`CreationPolicy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html).

The bootstrapping script which installs the CloudFormer application is failing at or before the final step which to run `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal` to inform CloudFormation that the application installed correctly.

The bootstrapping scripts log to `/var/log/setup_cloudformer.log` so you might be able to get more information about why it's failing by looking in there.

To try and investigate you could choose the `Launch More Like This` action on the EC2 instances page to launch another CloudFormer WebServer instance. You can then provide a keypair and update the Security Group to allow SSH access to look at the logs.

Comment: to my understanding, CloudFormer stack will be created by Amazon itself and I should not be involved in the process, however, I have checked the instance and it was indeed created before the rollback but I was unable to login to the web server.

Comment: I updated my answer now I know it's the CloudFormer stack itself that's failing to launch rather than the stack that it generated.

Comment: I am having same issue using default cloudformation cloud former.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Anush Arvind, you also must take care not to include special characters in the password.

From the official docs:

> You can't leave the password blank, and you can't use special
>   characters in the password (such as ; & ! " £ $ % ^ ( ) / ).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html